# Forcing CLGeocoder block code to run synchroniously

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I use `CLGeocoder` to geocode a list of addresses so that certain kinds of information can be shown to the user in a `UITableView`. However, all of the `CLGeocoder` geocoding and reverse geocoding methods take as a parameter a block of code that is run asynchronously from the rest of the program whenever the geocoding request is complete:

```
- (void)geocodeAddressString:(NSString *)addressString 
completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler
```

Is there a way to force this code to run synchronously *(i.e. force the program to wait for the geocoding request to complete and wait for it to be processed by the handler before moving on)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. And if there were, it would be a very bad idea (at least if you ran this asynchronously on the main thread). You have no control over how long the geocoding process would take (could be dozens of seconds in case of a server timeout) and if it took longer than about 5 seconds, the OS's watchdog timer would immediately kill your app because it no longer responds.